# json schema to ensure a string does not match any element of an array

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

```
{
  "title":"x",
  "type:"string",
  "doesNotMatch":["element1","element2"]
}
```

Is there JSON schema which ensures that the JSON data will not match element1 and element2.

- `{"x":element1}` is invalid
- `{"x":"daf"}` valid provided "daf" is not equal to element1 and element2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`not` `enum` should help you:

```
{
  "title":"x",
  "type:"string",
  "not": {"enum":["element1","element2"]}
}
```

Comment: Just for Punit Kulal reference: please see: http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#logic as well as e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48045287/2811843 for some clarifications on translating boolean logic into JSON Schema